# pthread for processes with more than one parameter

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm currently creating a program that uses threads to process BMP images. The thing is... I know that pthread uses as arg 4 the signature of the function... But how could I create a thread if the function needs more than 1 parameters?

Here's the struct needed by the function:

```
typedef struct {
HEADER header;
INFOHEADER infoheader;
PIXEL *pixel;
} IMAGE;

IMAGE imagenfte,imagendst;
```

Heres the function code:

```
void *processBMP(IMAGE *imagefte, IMAGE *imagedst)
{
int i,j;
int count=0;
PIXEL *pfte,*pdst;
PIXEL *v0,*v1,*v2,*v3,*v4,*v5,*v6,*v7;
int imageRows,imageCols;
memcpy(imagedst,imagefte,sizeof(IMAGE)-sizeof(PIXEL *));
imageRows = imagefte->infoheader.rows;
imageCols = imagefte->infoheader.cols;
imagedst->pixel=(PIXEL *)malloc(sizeof(PIXEL)*imageRows*imageCols);
for(i=1;i<imageRows-1;i++){
for(j=1;j<imageCols-1;j++)
{
pfte=imagefte->pixel+imageCols*i+j;
v0=pfte-imageCols-1;
v1=pfte-imageCols;
v2=pfte-imageCols+1;
v3=pfte-1;
v4=pfte+1;
v5=pfte+imageCols-1;
v6=pfte+imageCols;
v7=pfte+imageCols+1;
pdst=imagedst->pixel+imageCols*i+j;
...
}

...
int main()
{
int res;

///////Variables a utilizar en Hilo///////
int procBMP_t;  //Variable entera para la creación de los hilos
pthread_t proc_t;  //Hilo para el procesamiento del BMP
//////////////////////////////////////////

...
procBMP_t = pthread_create(&proc_t, NULL, processBMP, (void *) &imgsSENT);  //Hilo para el procesamiento de imagenes
```

I tried this to solve it with this:

```
struct threadImgs{   //Estructura para enviar ambas imagenes como argumento del thread
IMAGE fuente;
IMAGE destino;
};

struct threadImgs imgsSENT;


void *processBMP(void *imgs)
{

struct threadImgs* imagen = (struct threadImgs *) imgs;

IMAGE *imagefte = imagen->fuente;
IMAGE *imagedst = imagen->destino;
....
}
```

But it doesn't really help, can't even compile due to "incompatible types when initializing type struct error"

Any help D:???

Comment: pass array of arguments or wrap with a structure which contains two fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach wrapping both parameters into a strcuture is the way to go.

However mind the types:

```
struct threadImgs
{   
  IMAGE fuente;
  IMAGE destino;
};
```

The struct above defines it's elements to be instances of `IMAGE`.

Your thread functions tries to access pointers to `IMAGE`:

```
void *processBMP(void *imgs)
{
  struct threadImgs* imagen = (struct threadImgs *) imgs;

  IMAGE *imagefte = imagen->fuente;
  IMAGE *imagedst = imagen->destino;

  ...
```

So either change the struct to define its elements to be pointers:

```
struct threadImgs 
{   
  IMAGE * fuente;
  IMAGE * destino;
};
```

Or chnages the thread function to not pull pointers:

```
void *processBMP(void *imgs)
{
  struct threadImgs * imagen = (struct threadImgs *) imgs;

  IMAGE imagefte = imagen->fuente;
  IMAGE imagedst = imagen->destino;

  ...
```

Comment: Or just do `IMAGE *imagefte = &imagen->fuente;`

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to use comments to thank users buy... @alk This worked perfectly, thanks a lot for answering my (perhaps silly) question!!